# Bucket with balls

Tags: probability

We have 10 white , 20 black and 30 red balls ,comparable to each other,   in a bucket and we randomly select 4 without any preference, with refitting. What's the probability to:

A: Have picked at least one white ball???
B: Knowing that we havent picked any red balls, what's the probability to have picked at least and white ball???

C:Knowing that we have picked at least one white ball, whats the probability to have picked 0 red balls???

FIND A,B,C probabilities

Answer (score 0):

A. Instead of finding the probability of at least one white ball, try to find the probability of getting no white balls. HINT: You must choose 4 from the 50 non-white balls, out of all possible choices of 4 from 60 balls. Think combinations.

B. This is a conditional problem. Use the formula $$P(a|b)={P(a and b)\over P(b)}$$ to find the answer. HINT: Do the same trick as in A. What's the chance of getting no red or white balls? In general, what's the chance of getting no red balls?

C. This is the reverse of B. The following formula will help: $$P(b|a)=\frac{P(b)}{P(a)}P(a|b)$$